# Why did they avoid parodying Martian Manhunter?

Tags: character, the-boys

*The Boys* is based on the comic book of the same name. In comics, they have a team called The Seven which is a clear parody of *Justice League*:

- The Homelander (Superman parody)
- Black Noir (Batman parody)
- Queen Maeve (Wonder Woman parody)
- Mister Marathon (Flash parody)
- The Deep (Aquaman parody)
- Jack From Jupiter (Martian Manhunter parody)
- The Lamplighter (Green Lantern parody)

Later A-Train replaced Mister Marathon, maybe a Barry Allen/Wally West angle. And later Starlight replaced Lamplighter and she is most probably original character rather than JL parody as discussed in [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/102378/1190).

But when it comes to the show there was no Jack From Jupiter and he is replaced with Translucent who is far from resembling Martian Manhunter and becomes the only anomaly to parody the seven of Justice League.

So what was the reason for this change? Is it some budget issue to stick with heroes with a human face or they wanted to keep it different from Justice League?

Comment: If they get an alien, then that alien couldn't be easy to *made a supe* from Compound V, probably. different POV

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The showrunners didn't want an alien superhero in the world they were creating and with the story they wanted to tell. (It should go without saying but there are spoilers here.) [This article](https://www.cbr.com/the-boys-jack-from-jupiter-season-2/) on cbr.com includes quotes from an Entertainment Weekly interview and a Reddit AMA (Ask Me Anything).

From the [EW interview](https://ew.com/tv/2019/07/30/the-boys-season-1-ending-cameos-season-2/) (emphasis mine):

> In an interview with Entertainment Weekly, series co-creator of The Boys Erik Kripke explained the decision not to use Jack in the show, saying: “**No gods from mythology, no aliens from other planets.** It’s only humans who suddenly found themselves with these extraordinary abilities.”

From the Reddit AMA (emphasis mine):

> We're trying to make the show as grounded as possible -- and the story to the public is that people were suddenly and spontaneously born with these powers. (That's not the truth of course, but Vought is pitching a Mutant like mythology to the public). **To say one of their heroes is an alien kinda kills that myth**. Jack always felt too fantastic for the world we were trying to create. Though I do love his ability to get that many penises into his butt.

Answer (score 3):

Well *Jack From Jupiter* isn't seen or heard of in season 1, and that's the case season 2, **except** in S02E07, Lamplighter and and another character (who's name I've removed due to potential spoilers for those who haven't watched S02E06) are watching Supe porn. And I didn't catch him, but an actor is credited as "Porn Jack From Jupiter":

[image]

Edit: Oooh, courtesy the web (Reddit actually), I managed to find [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/7CQZqFL96dse7eS89) photo. Expect the "real" *Jack From Jupiter* to be a bald guy (and slightly, *orange?*), if he does show up.

---

**TLDR:** *Jack From Jupiter* does exist in the show, and we haven't seem him yet; just his pornographic counterpart.

Comment: "Jack From Jupiter does exist in the show, and we haven't seem him yet" I don't think that's necessarily indicated, at all. Most likely just an Easter egg.