# How accurate is 'The Boys' series to the comics?

Tags: the-boys, comparison

I am a big fan of the amazon series 'The Boys' and after watching it for a second time decided to look into the source material that is based on, the comic book series of the same name.

I noticed differences, a major one being the black noir eventually killed homelander, but in the series, homelander killed noir at the end of season 3.  Barring some twist where noir comes back I assume that will not be the case in the show.

Subsequently, I've come to wonder, are there any other major differences between the comics and the show? Seeing as the original comic writers are 2 of the executive producers on the show, I thought it would be pretty accurate, so how accurate really is it?

Comment: I've seen the show and read the comics. They're pretty close. Some events have been missed and some characters consolidated but overall if you enjoy the show you'll like the comics. A word of warning, the comics feature frontal nudity

Comment: Still, while not too great, there's lots of differences, afaik

Comment: related https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/102796/why-did-they-avoid-parodying-martian-manhunter